# Is modal logic too coarse-grained?

Tags: modal-logic, bayesian

Modal logic has "necessary" operators (true in all worlds) and "possible" operators (true in some world).  Compare this to probability, where only probabilities of 1 would be "necessary" and any positive probability would be "possible."  (Some events with probability 0 could be "possible" as well if they have measure 0, and some events could have probability 1 without being necessary if their complement has measure 0).  Modal logic thus seems very coarse-grained, distinguishing few cases compared to probability.

Is it too coarse-grained?  In Bayesian statistics we would never assign any probability of exactly 0 to any event that isn't logically self-contradictory; we would assign a nonzero probability to the possibility that the room is full of pink elephants, or last-thursdayism, or the notion that one is a Boltzmann brain.  So by this view, every proposition that isn't logically impossible is "possible."

Also in Bayesian statistics we would never assign a probability of exactly 1 to any event that isn't logically necessary.  We would not place a probability of 1 on the proposition that Earth exists.  So by this view, no proposition that isn't logically necessary is "necessary."

So everything logically possible is possible and nothing that isn't logically required is necessary, stripping modal logic of almost all meaning.  Yes?  No?

One might object that Bayesian inference is subjective and modal logic is not, so that modal possibility does not translate to Bayesian probability.  Well, what should we take for the set of all possible worlds, in order to grant meaning to modal logic?  I usually don't like mentioning quantum physics in philosophy, because it's so often misinterpreted.  But it's relevant here.  According to quantum physics, virtually no physical condition is necessary; we only have probabilities of a system being found in different configurations, and just like in Bayesian inference, these probabilities are neither exactly 0 nor exactly 1 for almost any event.

Comment: Modal logic has many versions and many applications. Some versions may be too coarse, or otherwise inappropriate, for some applications, but to say that modal logic itself is too coarse in some absolute sense is rather unfair.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you tell me more about which versions are appropriate for applications, and what assumptions those versions make to avoid the problem I described (in which everything is possible and nothing is necessary)?

Comment: Everything logically possible is possible and nothing that isn't logically required is necessary only if you take logical possibility as the interpretation of your modal formalism. One can instead take physical possibility (so energy conservation is necessary) or epistemic possibility (possible as far as we know) or even moral permissibility instead. Modal formalism does not care how □ and ◇ are interpreted as long as the axioms hold, and keeping it coarse-grained relieves one of the need to figure out exact 'probabilities' when they are superfluous to the task or indeterminate.

Comment: @Conifold energy is not perfectly conserved in QM; a system may randomly be observed at a higher or lower energy than it started with (energy is only conserved on average).  It's unclear if this is a problem of QM or a problem with energy conservation.  Energy is also only locally conserved in general relativity.  Perhaps you are right that modal logic has applications if you interpret possibility as moral possibility - epistemic possibility has the same problem though.  As far as we know, virtually any physical condition might be possible.

Comment: @Conifold clarification:  energy is not perfectly conserved through wavefunction collapse in QM.  It is conserved at other times, and it is conserved if wavefunction collapse doesn't happen.  See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298801/wavefunction-collapse-and-energy-conservation-and-stationary-tunneling or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2184329_Wavefunction_Collapse_and_Conservation_Laws .  For GR there is apparently controversy, but see https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html

Comment: Who cares? For most practical purposes not only is energy conserved, but all of classical physics can be assumed to hold. Modal logic is often applied to everyday contexts where even more pragmatic constraints are imposed, e.g. that people can't fly, do not have three hands, etc.

Comment: @Conifold how can you rigorously justify such constraints?  Or I guess more to the point, how do you rigorously set up a modal logic that has these constraints?  Can you give an example of a modal logic set up with some arbitrary constraints like that?

Comment: It seems like if your modal logic has rules for how events can cause other events, then arbitrary constraints like "people can't have three hands" would contradict the causal rules, because it is possible to have a causal chain of events resulting in a person with three hands.  So I guess it's a question of what kind of rules you would be able to allow in such a logic, maybe not causal ones.

Comment: Modal logic is set up regardless of what the constraints are, it is only when interpreting □A and ◇A that you decide what constraints you want. The only requirement is that they are spelled out and applied uniformly to all statements, but it has no effect on manipulating modal formulas. Whatever "causal rules" you adopt they are not part of modal logic, and it is your responsibility to avoid inconsistent premises just as with ordinary logic. But I wouldn't worry too much, laws of physics are too weak to derive that humans exist at all.

Comment: +1 This q isn't really worth DV as it raises a valid point, albeit there's there issue that "modal logic" isn't just one logic...

Answer (score 2):

Modal logic, if you think of it as just the augmentataion of an underlying logic with the box and diamond operators, is indeed limited in many ways, but it is still highly useful. The possible worlds semantics that usually accompanies it is even more expressive than the box/diamond calculus. It is not a replacement for probability theory, though it is not antithetical to it either. Indeed I have seen papers where the authors use the set of all possible worlds as a surrogate for the event space. So one could still speak of the probability of some event in terms of the relative abundance of the accessible possible worlds in which it happens. That said, if you want to do probability calculations, you will still need the probability calculus. One can think of probability as a way of quantifying possibilities.

But modal logic has many other applications, and possible world semantics has even more.

For example, possible world semantics gives us a handle on the intensional component of the meanings of predicates. Consider a pair of predicates that answer to the expressions 'species of animal that has a heart' and 'species of animal that has kidneys'. These have distinct meanings, but they are coextensive in the actual world. We could distinguish their meanings by appeal to what is true in possible worlds that contain animals that satisfy one but not the other.

David Lewis and Robert Stalnaker both deploy possible worlds to explain the meaning of conditionals, especially counterfactuals. A conditional 'if A then B' is true if B is true in the closest possible world in which A is true, where closeness is assessed by means of a bunch of heuristics. Understanding conditionals like this helps to explain how conditionals can range over possibilities that are non-actual, though there are plenty of rival accounts.

Possible worlds allow us to speak of properties of things that are necessary *de re*. According to Saul Kripke, some properties of individuals are essential, and by the causal theory of names, most names rigidly designate their referents across possible worlds. In Kripke's account, this explains why the concepts of necessity and a priority come apart and we can have propositions that are a posteriori necessary or a priori contingent.

Modal logic is not only about necessity and possibility. There are modal logics that are concerned with belief (doxastic), knowledge (epistemic), obligation (deontic), and many others. These do not all obey the same logic, which is one reason why there are many distinct systems of modal logic. The logical necessity (or to be more precise, the smallest modal companion) of classical logic is S5, while that of intuitionistic logic is S4 (by the Gödel-McKinsey-Tarski translation). The logic of provability in a formal system is K4W.

For applications of modal logic like these, we don't need a fine-grained probability calculus. A formal system either proves some proposition or it doesn't. Under a deontic logic, an action is obligatory or it isn't. Two names identify the same referent, or they don't. To speak of probabilities as you do suggests you are using 'probability' to represent a degree of credence, in order to quantify uncertainty. This is fine, but it is only one kind of modality: a modality of doxastic uncertainty. Modal logics can represent all kinds of modalities that have nothing to do with uncertainty.

--- edited to address comment by the OP

The axiomatisation isn't the issue. Modal logics do not of themselves cause a modal collapse under which propositions drop out as all necessary or all possible. The issue is the interpretation of the box and diamond. If we interpret diamond as 'it is physically possible that' then definitely lots of things are physically possible, though not everything: perpetual motion machines, faster than light travel, the elixir of life, me being able to fly just by waving my arms, are things that are physically impossible as far as we know. Anything that violates the laws of nature remains impossible. If we interpret box to mean 'it is a legal obligation under English law that' then not everything is possible, because not everything is permissible under English law. If we interpret box to mean 'it is provable in some formal system R that' then presumably some propositions are indeed provable, and so their negations are not provable. Modal logic is quite flexible as to its interpretations and it is down to the user to select the appropriate logic for the intended interpretation. Incidentally, if you haven't already read it, you might enjoy George Boolos' book, "The Logic of Provability" in which he shows, via [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem), how the modal logic K4W (also called GL) can be used to express what is provable in Peano arithmetic, so that results like Gödel's second incompleteness theorem feature as theorems of the logic, without the need for the usual apparatus of Gödel numbering.

Comment: Okay, but with regard to necessity and possibility operators and the possible-worlds semantics, how can they be axiomatized so that they do not yield everything as possible and nothing as necessary?  Do you have an example of that being done?  Or an example of how can they be used in conjunction with a probability space?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically true that modal operators (alone) have trouble capturing the subtleties of probabilities, in a way that doesn't lose a lot of inference power in the resulting logic.

To give you a basic insight here (or maybe to just exemplify what the question asserts) as to why this is difficult, a basic ‘probable’
modal operator (which I'm gonna call is-likely) was e.g. [suggested by Hamblin](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-probability/#QualReprUnce) with the meaning of exceeding some set probability value (e.g. 0.5). Alas doing much inference that "logic" way (instead of calculating probabilities) doesn't work too well because that operator is not a normal modal operator, meaning that

```
P1: is-likely x 
P2: is-likely y
```

does *not* (semantically) entail that

```
C:  is-likely (x and y) .
```

in all instances. So `is-likely` is basically [non-adjunctive](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10992-004-8539-5) (which I think it entails that it's [not normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_modal_logic) either.)

One approach is to "fix the semantics" by resorting to [neighborhood semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborhood_semantics) and this was done e.g. by [HA Costa](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10992-004-8539-5) who gives such semantics to a minimal adjunctive modal logic. As interesting as that may be from a mathematically or "pure logic" perspective, I didn't see much suggested in terms of applications for that approach (in that paper anyway).

If you peruse some other recent literature of probabilistic logic, probabilities basically have to be introduced as actual numbers to say more meaningful things. As SEP notes that's generally done along the lines of:

> A basic modal probability logic adds to propositional logic formulas of the form
> P
> (
> ϕ
> )
> ≥
> q
> , where
> q
> is typically a rational number, and
> ϕ
> is any formula of the language, possibly a probability formula. The reading of such a formula is that the probability of
> ϕ
> is at least
> q
> .

But you cold argue that having modalities "with numbers attached" isn't quite a "pure modal" logic. Although as SEP also notes:

> This general reading of the formula does not reflect any difference between modal probability logic and other probability logics with the same formula; where the difference lies is in the ability to embed probabilities in the arguments of probability terms and in the semantics.

Then SEP provide an example which mixes probabilities with (Knightian) uncertainty. In that context, in which you're not wiling to make probability assessments about some statements, it seems to make some compelling sense to have both explicit probability statements and modal operators. Without working through their example, they e.g. show a formula

> ¬
> □
> h
> ∧
> (
> ¬
> □
> P
> (
> h
> )
> =
> 1
> /
> 2
> )
> ∧
> (
> ♢
> P
> (
> h
> )
> =
> 1
> /
> 2
> )
> . This can be read as it is not known that
> h
> is true, and it is not known that the probability of
> h
> is
> 1
> /
> 2
> , but it is possible that the probability of
> h
> is
> 1
> /
> 2
> .

However that you can well argue that modal operators are properly dealing only with the latter aspect (Knightian) uncertainty in this approach. (Some other mathematical [not "purely logical"] approaches have been [suggested](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11579-017-0191-2) for Knightian uncertainty, but that's besides the point here.)